# Why pass dummy object to Event Handler in C#?

Tags: c#, events

the following is a function that invokes the event and thus notifies all clients.

```
public static void OnEventXYZ(XYZEventArgs e)
{
    if(EventXYZ!=null)
        EventXYZ(new object(),e);
}
```

This is from a sample code.

What i want to know is "What is the significance of `new object()`?

is this a syntax followed or only for this situation?

Comment: if you do not have it, then how would you know from whom the event got raised? and what to do about the event based on the sender type ?

Comment: Sending parameter of Object type helps in knowing which event raised the event handler?

Comment: No, who raised it. The second parameter will tell you what kind of event was raised

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Normally you pass *this* as the sender parameter of an event handler.

However, in this case, the event is static so you cannot use *this*. The person who wrote that sample chose to pass `new object()` instead. I think most people would pass `null` instead but that's really a matter of personnal preference.

Comment: Because then you're not creating another new object for every single event invocation.

Answer (score 2):

That parameter is for the sender of the event. Normally, you would use `this`, but that will not work in the static context.

Answer (score 1):

EventXYZ seems to have been written to expect a sender (typical with event handlers). In the case of the static "On"blahBlah event raiser, the sender isn't really dealt with clearly. As another responder posted, it seems to be an attempt to satisfy the sender property of the event args that are passed along to the handler.

A more correct implementation would likely either omit the sender from the EventArgs or allow the static "OnBlahBlah" method an argument that allows the caller to specify the sender.

The use of "new object()" in this case seems like confusing fluff, IMHO. But, then again, we don't technically know the signature of the constructor being used in this case... perhaps the first argument is meant to be "Some random object that will be used as the thing we can blame later when your hard drive gets formatted".. maybe a new, empty, meaningless object is perfect for this.

Another thing to look for is that you may consider rewriting the code to be this:

```
public static void OnEventXYZ(XYZEventArgs e)
{
    var evt = EventXYZ;
    if(evt != null)
        evt(new object(),e);
}
```

.. In a nutshell, that is a typical  "sender as first argument" pattern that you see in 99% of event args / event handlers. Better examples will probably make more sense.

You can also use ILSpy or Reflector to look at the thousands of event raisers/handlers in the .NET runtime to get better examples of how the common patterns are coded.

*EDIT: BTW, it's unusual to see static OnEvent raisers... it's a little odd. Not technically correct, but it sure messes up the typical "'this' as sender" pattern.*

Cheers!